# How to read properties with ":" colon in key name

Tags: java, properties

How to read properties, which having in key name ":" character?

In actual default use properties, colon is taken as delimiter too..

Any ideas how to ?

`keyPrefix:keySuffix = value`

`keyPrefix:keySuffix` is meant as whole name where `:` is part of it.

I know there is also possibility to store/read properties as XML format, but its not acceptable (customers "noobs" wont read XML `:)` ).

I also know that I could make my own parser, but I before I do, I would better know other easier solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugly, but needs a backslash as instead of a `=`, one might use a colon.
More,customer-friendly would be a minus sign!.

```
keyPrefix\:keySuffix = value
```

.